Auto-upload not opened files (but changed) in Visual Studio Code via ftp-sync
I'm working on a web project with VSC.
Local files are conected with the server via FTP-sync extension.
I'm using a Sass processor (Prepros) for working in CSS files.
When I save a file on working, that file is automatically uploaded to the server with the last changes.
When I save the .scss file, this file is also auto uploaded, but the processed .css file not. Even if it has new changes.
I check the auto-save settings from VSC and I enabled the File>Auto Save option. That works fine for opened files, but not for the closed ones.
Not a big surprise actually.
But I want to know if there is a way for auto-uploading closed files that where changed in background in VSC.
Thanks in advance.
